# Add Database Relationship to craft_user table from a Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, database

Within a plugin I'd like to create a table which is linked to the `craft_users` table, keyed on the `id`. In my table I have a `user_id` column which I'd like to be unique and only contain Id's which exist in the `craft_users` table. Now, I know I can't monkey about with the `craft_users` table or the `UserRecord`, so I wondered what the best way of doing this would be?

Here is my Record code:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_MerchantRecord extends BaseRecord
{
  public function getTableName()
  {
    return 'myplugin_merchants';
  }

  protected function defineAttributes()
  {
    return [
      'user_id' => [AttributeType::Number, 'required' => true],
      ...
    ];
  }

  public function defineIndexes()
  {
      return [
          ['columns' => ['user_id'], 'unique' => true],
      ];
  }

  public function defineRelations()
  {
    return [
      'user' => [static::BELONGS_TO, 'UserRecord', 'user_id'],
    ];
  }
}
```

If I try and install the plugin I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint. 
The SQL statement executed was: ALTER TABLE `craft_myplugin_merchants`    
ADD CONSTRAINT `craft_myplugin_merchant_user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
REFERENCES `craft_users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

I've tried it with/without the `defineIndexes()` call, and get the same error. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't see the wood for the trees!

As always any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like I had a couple of things wrong here.

1. The type of relationship I was trying to use.
2. The fact that I was trying to add an extra unique index.

To solve the problem, what I ended up doing was this:

- Remove my `user_id` column.
- Remove the `defineIndexes()` definition altogether (you'll see why in a minute).
- Change my Relationship definition to this:

  ```
  public function defineRelations()
  {
    return [
      'user' => [static::BELONGS_TO, 'UserRecord',  'id', 'required' => true, 
                      'onDelete' => static::CASCADE],
    ];
  }
  ```

So what this ended up doing was using the `id` column that is automatically created as both a `Primary Key` and a `Foreign Key` related to the `craft_user` table.

The reason I wanted to do this, is my new table which I'm creating is actually just an extension of the `craft_user` table anyway. There will be only ever one row per `User` (which is made unique by the `Primary Key` index) and the `Foreign Key` makes sure that only values that exist in the `craft_users` `id` column are allowed in the `id` column of my new table.

For completeness, the reason I was getting the error mentioned in the question was because I'd set the `user_id` column to `'required' => true`. As I'd not used the `onDelete` property on the relationship, it was defaulting to `ON DELETE SET NULL`. It can't be both, either it must always have a value or it can be set to `NULL`.